# How can I get the URI of the previous page in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

The problem is the target platform I am using (WP 7.1) doesn't have this property "BackStack" in the "NavigationService" class. Now, how can I solve this problem in my current platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.backstack%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), BackStack is available on WP7.1.

> In Windows Phone OS 7.1, functionality has been added to the NavigationService API for working with, and enabling the inspection of, the navigation history.

Comment: thanks i checked my target platform and it was WP7.0 instead of 7.1, so upgrading solved my problem.